# CV URI Taken by SO Careers Profile

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

**Update: I had gotten an invitation on a different email than I used for SO. I've removed that URL, but now I have a new question: Can I completely delete the old account?**

Old question follows:

I started a CV back before [Jobs] existed, which is at https://stackoverflow.com/cv/virtualdxs/. Now I want to use that URI for the new one, but I get "that url is already taken," and I can't figure out how to access that old one. What do I do?

Comment: I had a CV back before Jobs existed, too. It was automatically migrated to Jobs. Don't try and create a *new* one. Was the old CV not linked to your current Stack Overflow account?

Comment: I'm now remembering, didn't Careers used to be separate? Let me dig through my email and see if there's a separate account.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. I had gotten an invitation on a separate email. Updating the question.